# Terraform get IP from hostname

Tags: terraform

Does Terraform have an easy way to get the IP address from the hostname?

Something like this

```
data "some_data" "fetch_ip" {
  url = "https://google.com"
}

resource "null_resource" "temp" {
  google_ip = data.some_data.fetch_ip.ip // ipv4: 123.123.123.123
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Terraform's [`dns` provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/dns/latest/docs) provides data sources for reading DNS records for a given host.

If you are looking for the IPv4 addresses for eg `google.com` then you would need to use the [`dns_a_record_set` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/dns/latest/docs/data-sources/dns_a_record_set). In fact, the data source's documentation gives an example that looks up the A record for `google.com`:

```
data "dns_a_record_set" "google" {
  host = "google.com"
}

output "google_addrs" {
  value = "${join(",", data.dns_a_record_set.google.addrs)}"
}
```

or for HCL2/Terraform 0.12+ syntax:

```
data "dns_a_record_set" "google" {
  host = "google.com"
}

output "google_addrs" {
  value = join(",", data.dns_a_record_set.google.addrs)
}
```